# Entity table exists but I cannot access it through Model

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2019

I am using C#, .NET 4.6 and EF 6.13 in Visual Studio 2019. I started having issues with a new table I added to the database and then refreshed my model. I then refreshed model.

When I went to access it in code, I get this message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type DebtCollectionBatch is not part of the model for the current context.
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
> at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
> at SuburbanWebService.SuburbanService.SaveDebtCollectionsBatchTotal(BatchTotalDebtCollections batchTotal) in D:\Repos\Suburban\ServiceApiRepo\SuburbanWebService\SuburbanWebService\SuburbanService.svc.cs:line 417

I tried refreshing model again and after several failed attempts to get it to work, I deleted that model, saved and restarted VS. I created a completely new model this time. Now, I cannot access the table in code, well partially, if that makes any sense.

[image]

The code I am attempting to add:

```
public bool SaveDebtCollectionsBatchTotal(BatchTotalDebtCollections batchTotal)
{
  var dt = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

  try
  {
    using (var entity = new SuburbanWebServiceEntities())
    {
      var bt = new DebtCollectionBatch();
      bt.DebtCollectionsBatchId = Guid.NewGuid();
      bt.DebtCollectionsCount = batchTotal.AchCount;
      bt.DebtCollectionsCompany = batchTotal.DebtCollectionsCompany;
      bt.CompanyCode = batchTotal.CompanyCode;
      bt.DateTimeSubmitted = DateTime.Now; // dt;
      bt.DollarTotal = batchTotal.DollarTotal;

      entity.d  <-- fails here

      entity.SaveChanges();
      WriteLog.WriteToLogFile("SaveDebtCollectionsBatchTotal",
        $"Successfully saved ach transactions for {batchTotal.CompanyCode} on {dt}. Transaction count: {batchTotal.AchCount} for ${batchTotal.DollarTotal}.");
    }

    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    WriteLog.WriteToLogFile("SaveDebtCollectionsBatchTotal",
      $"Failed to save debt collection batch total transaction for {batchTotal.CompanyCode} on {dt}. Transaction count: {batchTotal.AchCount} for ${batchTotal.DollarTotal}. See exception log.",
      ex);
    return false;
  }
}
```

I checked the connection string for duplicates or for it to be pointing to the wrong location and it seems correct:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SuburbanWebServiceEntities" 
         connectionString="***" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>`
```

This is my table:

[image]

This has be completely confused. I can create a new `DebtCollectionBatch` but I cannot add it, it doesn't find it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your biggest problem is that you're still using EDMX. I strongly recommend moving to code-first mode, maybe even to EF-core, if possible. That said, we can't see why EF didn't create the navigation property in the generated class. That's the issue and we have no information how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is there a project with the name **DebtCollectionBatchContext.cs**. Check if the code exists:

> `public DbSet<DebtCollectionBatch> DebtCollectionBatch { get; set; };`

2.You can add code directly at the beginning of **DebtCollectionsBilling.cs**:

> `public DbSet<DebtCollectionBatch> DebtCollectionBatch { get; set; }`